# Bootstrap: seven same size columns in two rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Any idea on how to keep the same size for each column but center the second row...

(In another word, create a 1.5 column)

```
<div class="container""
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            1
        </div> <!-- close .col -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            2
        </div> <!-- close .col -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
           3
        </div> <!-- close .col -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            4
        </div> <!-- close .col -->
    </div><!-- close .row-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
            5
        </div> <!-- close .col -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            6
        </div> <!-- close .col -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            7
        </div> <!-- close .col -->
    </div><!-- close .row-->
</div><!-- close container -->
```

Comment: Do you want the first two columns in row #1 to match the first column of row #2?

Comment: Actually, the the first row has already the correct shape, but I want the second row centered, following this structure:
row1 :  3   3   3    3
row2 : 1.5  3 3 3  1.5

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the example but as you can see on it, the col n°6 is not well centered compared to col N° 2 & 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are essentially offsetting by 1.5, you can create your own offset class like this:

```
.col-sm-offset-1point5 {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
}
```

Note that 12.5% is one eighth of the width of a row which is your 1.5 column offset. Now apply it to your first column in the second row (replace `col-sm-offset-1` with `col-sm-offset-1point5`)

Example here:
http://www.bootply.com/1rBTZPGsYu

Comment: + one for a simple, zen solution

Comment: Yes, one class added with one style. Zen is all about oneness.

Comment: I guess I'll go and do some Zen meditation, and hopefully I'll get the extra 11 rep I need to hit 200 for today!

Comment: You're my new favourite StackOverflower! And one good turn deserves another. Karma as well as Zen...

Answer (score 3):

*One other way is :*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/NWkWutLI8M

**CSS**:

```
.centered{
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: none; 
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            1
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            2
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-3">
           3
        </div> <!-- close .col -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9 centered">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
               6
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                 7
            </div>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```